# stripping of some tags of xml document

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a xml doc as below.

```
<data>
     <employee>
       <moretag> may or may not contain inner tag and attributes</moretag>
       <somemore>  may contain inner tags</somemore>
     </employee>
</data>
```

i want op as below

```
 <employee>
       <moretag> may or may not contain inner tag and attributes</moretag>
       <somemore>  may contain inner tags</somemore>
  </employee>
```

That is i want to strip off `data tags`.How can i do it?

Comment: Do you have preference to DOM vs SAX parsers?
Do you need it as pure text or as an object?

Comment: Looks like Thor's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jdom` for this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(xmlFileName);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(isr);

Element data = doc.getRootElement();
Element employee = data.getChild("employee");

XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOut.output(employee, System.out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply strip off some node like that.

The simple logic of what you tend to achieve is that you make a copy of firstChild of root node i.e.  and replace the root node with it.

P.S. that you have only one child under the root node.